# What is equivalent to grunt-contrib-compass in gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, compass

I am switching my project from grunt to gulp and need to add compass mixin to my code. So I am finding any task in gulp that can do much kind of work that `grunt-contrib-compass` do in grunt. I got this package `compass-mixins` but it has dependency to oudated repo of compass. Can anyone please help me out in finding that

Comment: compass is pretty much tied to ruby.  Why not try bourbon? It's an overkill to migrate. But if you are already in the process why not update the techstack.

Comment: Why bourbon? Although I cant change as working on a big project with multiple micro application linked. So one migration can take hell lots of code change. Thats y prefering to get same task as compared to grunt.